# Как быть с союзом "в случае(,) если"?

Tags: пунктуация

Примеры: "В случае(,) если представлены не все документы, заявителю может быть отказано в предоставлении услуги", "В случае(,) если представлены не все документы, ТО заявителю может быть отказано в предоставлении услуги". Так нужна ли запятая? И в обоих ли случаях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях возможны оба варианта пунктуации. Насколько понимаю, наличие "ТО" в 
основной части никак не влияет на грамматику, а следовательно и на выбор пунктуации.
Хотя поcледний случай действительно сложный, может меня и поправят. Я исхожу из  соображений, изложенных тут.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

В СЛУЧАЕ(,) ЕСЛИ, союз

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «в случае(,) если», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «если»). О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в [Прил. 3.](http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach3/)

Но в случае, если заблагорассудите сделать из сего моего письма какое-либо употребление, всепокорнейше прошу никак имени моего не упоминать... А. Пушкин, Повести покойного Ивана Петровича Белкина. **В случае если присяжные закатают меня, то я обращусь к своему старому другу…** А. Чехов, Ночь перед судом. Интересно знать, в случае если нам придется бежать, пойдет она с нами или нет? В. Обручев, Земля Санникова. Жилец приказал Анфисе, преданной и давней домашней работнице Анны Францевны, сказать, в случае если ему будут звонить, что он вернется через десять минут, и ушел вместе с корректным милиционером в белых перчатках. М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. В случае, если мы уберем войска из Курляндии, на каждую немецкую дивизию под Берлином будет приходиться по крайней мере три русские. Ю. Семенов, Семнадцать мгновений весны.

©gramota.ru

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно. Уточнение для автора вопроса. Вы путаете союз **в случае если** и двойной союз  **если...то**. Вторая часть союза "то" влияет на запятую в случае стечения (расположения рядом ) двух разных союзов. Например, Я знал, **что**, *если* пойду один, **обязательно заблужусь**. Я знал, **что** *если* пойду один, *то* **обязательно заблужусь**. В этих предложения рядом оказался союз **что** и союз **если (то)** При наличии второй части союза (ТО), запятая на месте стечения РАЗНЫХ союзов не ставится. А союз В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ - это один союз. Если Вам нужно сдавать экзамен по русскому языку - учите список союзов!

Comment: Благодарю. Но менторство неуместно.